# How to download elementary OS a second time?

Tags: download

I paid for elementary OS, downloaded the software but my installation failed.  I'm starting over and need to download again.  How do I go about this?  I have the confirm email receipt if needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on "Custom" put "0$" in the amount field, click on "Custom" again if it not selected, and then click Download button.